# how to set solr requestHandler

Tags: configuration, solr, requesthandler

data-config.xml
    
  
I add some setting infomation to solrconfig.xml,but show some error here:
how to set requestHandler???pls tell me how to set.thanks.
I don't know why shows this error.

---

> "point:
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   RequestHandler init failure"

---

Answer (score 0):

- Check to see if your RequestHandler class files are packaged properly in .jar file and they  are located in the lib directory of your core or at the standard library location.
- Make sure it's path is resolvable by the servlet container.
- Check for other exceptions piled while initializing your RequestHandler.
- Check for the log files inside the WebServer, for apche tomcat it is there in 'apache-tomcat-7.0.37\logs'.
- Make sure you are not missing any dependencies to be included.
- Paste your whole exception list for better glance of your problem.